# Can another telegram user make me access his bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

My friend has a tranding bot made with BotFather.

Is there a way to make the bot shared betweeen our account in a way we can use it together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot usernames are unique to each Telegram account and only that account is able to change the settings of the bot.

But you can make use of a bot through its API_TOKEN which you can get from botfather.

It looks like this:

`300123900:BARsAbMYBJv5wFhzNJ-Gbx678qpln7IgvzI`

If you share the token with anyone, they can use your bot. They will receive an error if they try to use it at the same time (calling `getUpdates` method from more than one instance would reject the caller except for the first one).

If by sharing you meant using the bot (not developing it), you can't do that unless the bot's developer designs it in a way that multiple Telegram accounts messaging the bot are considered one account.

Comment: By sharing i mean just see the message the bot send (for example of the bot places an order), Just receive messages in the app. I don't need my account to use It, just to see updates. The other account can use it

Comment: @DuccioBorchi You can write an MTPROTO API Bot to forward what your friend receives from the bot to your account. You can even write it in a way where what you send to your friend's Telegram gets forwarded to the bot.

Comment: I'm not so expert in programming a telegram bot, but I will give it a try. Is there a guide I can use to do it?

Comment: @DuccioBorchi Not a guide specific to this case, but you can study about [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/). You need to find out how to forward a message from one account to another. You can ask a new question regarding that if you needed help.